# Error with modded minecraft server boot on linux VM

Tags: linux, java

I'm running a VM with Linux (debian) for a modded minecraft server. A vanilla server runs just fine, but the modded server gives me this error when I bash the LaunchServer.bat. I think it has something to do with the java install, but don't know how to switch from Java 11.

```
root@minecraft:/home/MCEternal/Eternal (ServerPack 1.3.7)# bash LaunchServer.bat 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option PermSize; support was removed in 8.0
A problem occurred running the Server launcher.java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:70)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLC
lassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap
')
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.<init>(Launch.java:34)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
        ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was running the server on java 11, try switching to java 8 to run it.

You can use the command `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to select the java version you want to use from the ones you have installed.